# AngularJS filter model and sort by id list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have products model list

```
$scope.products=[{id:1,name:'product1'},{id:2,name:'product2'},{id:3,name:'product3'}, /*...*/]
```

and selected products (list of ids)

```
$scope.selectedProducts=[1,5,3,8,12]
```

I have to show only selected products in the same order as in the selectedProduct list

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply filters. Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XdaH/

Code for filter:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('filteredProducts', function(){

  return function(items,selectedProducts){
    var arrayToReturn = [];
    selectedProducts=[1,5,3];       
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        for(var j=0;j<selectedProducts.length;j++){
            if (items[i].id == selectedProducts[j]) {
            arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }            
    }

    return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```